# Problems with standard Search in Android 2.1. Running in another process?

Tags: android, android-2.1-eclair, android-searchmanager

My application use [standard search mechanism](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) (using searchable interface) and works well in all versions>2.1

In <3 I use Search Dialog and in >=3 I use SearchWidget and all works correctly. The problem is in 2.1 where I get `CrossProcessCursorException` from my `ContentProvider`:

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Only CrossProcessCursor cursors are supported across process for now`

It seems that Search dialog is run in another process in 2.1?
There's any way to workaround that?
Or I'm forced to implement CrossProcessCursor in my custom extended `CusorWrapper`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I haven't found any information about why in Android 2.1 you need to use a CrossProcessCursor.

But looking at SearchDictionary samples for 2.1 it uses a MatrixCursor and for newer android versions it uses a direct cursor from DB. Then I assumed that you simply need it because it work in this way.

I've tried two alternatives that both works:

1. Map the results with a MatrixCursor
2. Implement a CrossProcessCursorWrapperCompat taking the code from CrossProcessCursorWrapper from newer versions and adapting it to work in 2.1